# Java - Store array of objects as another object's value and call that value's field

Tags: java

I want to store item i1 and i2 as an array in user parameter items. I guess this part is OK.

```
class item {
    int quty;
    String name;
    double nc;

    public item(String name, int quty, double nc) {
        this.quty = quty;
        this.name = name;
        this.nc = nc;
    }

   static item i1 = new item("I1", 10, 6.04);
   static item i2 = new item("I2", 14, 8.01);
}

class user {
    String name;
    double nc;
    item[] items; // store item objects as value of user

    public user(String name, double nc, item[] items) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nc = nc;
            this.items=items;
    }

   static user u1 = new user("Tenny", 10.18, new item[]{item.i1, item.i2}  ); // user stores two items
}
```

Then I want to call items' names.
You can easly call item name by System.out.println(item.i1.name) , but I want to call names of items that user u1 has.

```
        System.out.println("User has " + Arrays.toString((user.u1.items.name)));
```

Above doesn't do that. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are calling is incorrect as Items is an array type it requires index.

```
user.u1.items[0].name
```

You can use below code to print the name of all item of user.

```
 for(item i:user.u1.items) { 
     System.out.println(i.name);  
  }
```